# Update value on success(using raty and bootstrap popover)

Tags: jquery, popover, raty

I am using bootstrap `popover` with `jquery-raty`. I have `hidden` div showing them on popover with JS function `content:`. I want to update some attribute in hidden div.
Suppose I've `data-rating` attribute in hidden div.  I want to update `data-rating` value. I am using following statement.

```
('#hidden_div_1`).data('rating', '25');
```

When I print data attribute `console.log($('#hidden_div_1').data('rating'));` I get `25` which is correct. But when I hover again on particular object to display the popover I get `old` attribue values. Value is `destroying when popover disappeared`. I don't know why. Any anyone help?

This is my [full jquery code](http://dpaste.org/eqLv9/).
This is small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZBW6/4/)

Thanks

EDIT 1: `$('#hidden_div_1').data('rating', '25');`

EDIT 2: It is strange. `data-rating` value is  not changing. I've attached `console.log` output.

[image: Console.log]

Code >

```
$('.link-container a').popover({
        content : function() { return $(this).siblings('.popover-content').html(); },
        trigger: 'click',
        html: true
    }).click(function(){
      $('.ratings').raty({
        score: function() { return $(this).attr('data-rating'); },
        click: function(score, evt, data) {
            //alert(score);
            var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log($("#"+currentId).data('rating'));
            alert(currentId);
            $("#"+currentId).attr('data-rating', score);
            console.log($("#"+currentId).data('rating'));
            $("#"+currentId).data('rating', score);
            console.log($("#"+currentId).data('rating'));

        },
          path: '/static/img/rating/',
      });
    });
```

`alert(currentId);` printing `correct` id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I looked at this in more detail, and the problem is that you are passing content to the Bootstrap popover.

This html content contains an ID (e.g. `#hidden_div_1`), but the problem is that any content you pass to the Bootstrap popover *gets replicated in that popover*.

In other words, you end up with duplicate IDs and JQuery does not know what element you are trying to reference.

So the solution is to put the data information into the container div (in this case `link-container`), like so:

```
<div class="link-container" data-rating="1" data-price="10">
    <a href="#" data-title="Title 1" id="r1">Click Here</a>
    <div class="temp-popover-content hidden">
        <p> Click on following images</p>
        <div class="ratings"></div>
        <p>Some content 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you can store data against this link-container without confusing JQuery, like so:

```
$('.link-container a').popover({
    content : function() { return $(this).siblings('.temp-popover-content').html(); },
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true
}).click(function(e) {
  // Added this because popovers get confused when more than one with a raty is open
  $('.link-container a').not(this).popover('hide');
  // storage refers to the link-container div
  var storage = $(this).parent();
  $('.ratings').raty({
        score: function() { return storage.data('rating'); },
        click: function(score, evt, data) {
            storage.data('rating', score);
            console.log("Data: "+storage.data('rating')); 
        }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/Qf5uU/11/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've attached `console.log` output and pasted `updated` code.

Comment: Many many thanks. I've wasted one day. But you saved my life. Awesome. Thanks alot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a '$'. It's supposed to be

```
$('#hidden_div_1').data('rating', '25');
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you end up with multiple elements with the same id in the DOM and that's a big NO-NO. Not sure how to fix the problem other than hard coding the div that is supposed to be used in the popover inside javascript for each element. If you are ok with that than let me know and I'll create a fiddle to illustrate.

Comment: That would be great if you create fiddle.

Comment: Sorry but can't seem to get it working. Might be a limitation of Bootstrap's popovers and you might look into creating your own or finding a different one.